# Pass object to onclick on appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I append several HTML-elements to my DOM and need to pass the object, that's used to create the element, to an onclick-function on the element.

I tried the following, but the object references always to the last instead of the current:

```
function addElementToList(obj){
    var elementHTML = '<li><a href="#">';
    elementHTML += obj.name + '<br>';
    elementHTML += '</a></li>';
    $('#list-canvas .elementList).append(elementHTML);

    $(this).click(function(){
        showDetails(obj);
    })
}
```

How can I pass the current element to the onclick-function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to create that elelemnt using jQuery in that case:

```
var element = $( '<li><a href="#">' + obj.name + '<br></a></li>' );
element.click(function(){
    showDetails(obj);
});
$('#list-canvas .elementList').append(element);
```